# Autoref to appendix with appendix package

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, appendices

I would like `autoref` to reference chapters in my appendix as `appendix <chapternumber>`. However it fails to print anything besides the chapternumber.
From the hyperref documentation page 16 where it states that `\appendixname` is set to `Appendix`, I would expect this functionality to work out of the box. I assume it has something to do with the fact, that I use the `appendices` enviornment instead of `\appendix`. How do I fix this?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{document}
\chapter{a}\label{a}
\autoref{a}.

\autoref{app}
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{app}\label{app}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Notice how it states `Chapter 1` but only `A` instead of `Appendix A`

[image: Missing Appendix infront of A]

I took a brief llok at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5785/19326, since it however seems to be available out of the box I would like to avoid using `cref`, since it states the links look worse.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The MWE generates the warning

```
Package hyperref Warning: No autoref name for `Appendix' on input line 11.
```

After defining

```
\newcommand*{\Appendixautorefname}{appendix}
```

the two `\autoref`s print "`chapter 1`" and "`appendix A`".

Comment: Since I use `todonotes` and still have [this issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126576/floatfoot-with-ffigbox-gives-warning) which both generate a lot of warnings, I failed to check the warnings page which is hidden by texstudio if there are no errors. I feel kind of stupid for this mistake, but your reference to the warning will preventme from making a similar mistake again. thank you.