# Display 'Appendix' instead of 'Section' when referencing to appendix in scrreport?

Tags: appendix

I want to display references to appendices as 'Appendix A' etc. At the moment, with the code below references show up as 'section A'. How can I adjust this?

```
\documentclass[appendixprefix = true]{scrreport}
\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix} % appendices
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
    \let\ref\autoref
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    This is a reference to the \ref{appendix:test}
    \appendix
    \include{appendix}
    \chapter*{Appendices}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
    \setcounter{section}{0}% Reset numbering for sections
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
    \section{Test}
    \label{appendix:test}
    \section{Another Test}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hyperref's `\autoref` does not make this easy. The following should work:

```
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\appendix}{} %
  {
    \gdef\theHchapter{\Hy@AlphNoErr{chapter}} % ❶
    \gdef\theHsection{\Hy@AlphNoErr{section}} % ❶
    \xdef\Hy@chapapp{\Hy@appendixstring} % ❷
    \def\Hy@chapterstring{section} % ❸
    \HyOrg@appendix % ❹
  }
\makeatother
```

The lines marked ❶ (adapted from the original redefinition of `\appendix` in hyperref make sure that you won't get an error if the chapter or section number is out of range. ❷ Is also adapted from the original definition which changes the label for appendixes to appendix (which will normally impact chapters. ❸ Is the key step here. We will have the `\appendix` command lie to hyperref and tell it that sections are the top-level command and should use the label from `\Hy@chapapp`. Finally ❹ calls the original `\appendix` definition saved by the hyperref package.

I've done something similar for my LaTeX book with cleveref to make references to sections and subsections of my appendices be labeled as appendices, but the current solution I have is pretty hacky and I don't care to share it right now (although I will eventually publish the document class on ctan).

Comment: Thanks for digging in. What does \makeatletter stand for? I'm getting an error 'Undefined control sequence. \RenewDocumentCommand'

Comment: `\makeatletter` gives access to private LaTeX commands. You also have an old LaTeX. You can replace the line `\RenewDocumentCommand{\appendix}{}' with `\renewcommand{\appendix}` but you really should update your LaTeX if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of `scrreport` or `\autoref` so this does not solve your problem but you may want to tidy up your code a bit:

```
% appendixprob.tex  SE 611452

\documentclass[appendixprefix = true]{scrreport}
\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix} % appendices
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
%    \let\ref\autoref  % is this causing the problem in scrreport?
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    This is a reference to the \ref{appendix:test}

%    \appendix
\begin{appendices} % using this saves a lot of your code
    \include{appendix} % we have no idea what is in appendix.tex
%    \chapter*{Appendices}
%    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
%    \setcounter{section}{0}% Reset numbering for sections
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
    \section{Test}
    \label{appendix:test}
    \section{Another Test}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do need to keep in \let\ref\autoref as it auto-prefixes Figures and Tables, which I've been using throughout my document. I think I have to define a new autoref for Appendices. I tried defining a command like in the answer here(https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112947/231879), but it doesn't work.

Comment: @dshgna Hopefully Don Hosel's answer will work for you, perhaps also with my tidying suggestions.